# Return transactions that have over X consecutive declined transactions before them within a time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following sample data with card transaction attempts (A - approved, D - declined) - only one card history here, but in the real data we'll have different cards and merchants. Txn ID is not necessarily in chronological order with the transactions.

How would we return all transactions where the conditions are met: Is declined and has 5 previous consecutive declines (approved transaction breaks the cycle) over rolling 5-day timeframe between the first decline and current transaction, with the same card, at the same merchant, with the same amount.

I've been trying with windowed functions but I'm having a hard time covering all the requirements.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [TxnID] int, [Card] varchar(16), [Merchant] varchar(7), [TxnDate] date, [TxnTime] time(0), [Amount] money, [Status] varchar(1) )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( 3168853, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-09T00:00:00', N'20:58:27', 43.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3179499, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'11:39:16', 31.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3178136, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'13:48:27', 33.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175356, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'20:50:29', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175336, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'20:55:12', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175286, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'21:08:19', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175256, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'21:16:21', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175149, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'21:44:48', 46.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175113, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'21:55:56', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175104, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'21:59:03', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175091, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'22:02:50', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3175061, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'22:12:05', 32.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3175057, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-10T00:00:00', N'22:13:21', 32.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3193276, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-12T00:00:00', N'21:14:29', 41.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3191126, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-12T00:00:00', N'21:58:09', 41.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3199288, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-13T00:00:00', N'05:15:52', 41.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3196882, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-13T00:00:00', N'14:09:23', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3196733, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-13T00:00:00', N'14:25:37', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3196611, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-13T00:00:00', N'14:38:51', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3200752, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-13T00:00:00', N'17:35:16', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3200713, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-13T00:00:00', N'17:40:55', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3207779, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-14T00:00:00', N'05:39:44', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3207774, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-14T00:00:00', N'05:49:54', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3207771, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-14T00:00:00', N'05:54:37', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3207769, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-14T00:00:00', N'05:58:23', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3205833, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-14T00:00:00', N'12:29:16', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3205737, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-14T00:00:00', N'12:38:56', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3205523, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-14T00:00:00', N'12:59:32', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3210112, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-15T00:00:00', N'14:24:40', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3209624, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-15T00:00:00', N'16:08:33', 32.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3209622, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-15T00:00:00', N'16:09:47', 33.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3209621, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-15T00:00:00', N'16:10:48', 31.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3209616, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-15T00:00:00', N'16:13:53', 32.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3209016, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-15T00:00:00', N'18:40:06', 33.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3208405, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-15T00:00:00', N'21:08:53', 33.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3219202, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-16T00:00:00', N'06:22:32', 32.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3218844, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-16T00:00:00', N'09:00:51', 34.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3217116, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-16T00:00:00', N'13:06:11', 34.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3215822, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-16T00:00:00', N'15:05:09', 33.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3214033, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-16T00:00:00', N'20:30:15', 38.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3214002, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-16T00:00:00', N'20:37:56', 38.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3213968, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-16T00:00:00', N'20:47:08', 38.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3225529, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'05:13:31', 41.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3225522, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'05:23:16', 41.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3225510, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'05:43:32', 41.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3225503, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'05:56:51', 41.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3225477, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'06:17:59', 33.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3224849, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'09:44:48', 33.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3224409, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'10:47:59', 31.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3224392, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'10:50:26', 31.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3224217, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'11:09:37', 31.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3222507, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'14:05:23', 31.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3220190, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-17T00:00:00', N'20:49:14', 31.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3233032, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'04:21:16', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3233029, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'04:26:57', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3233019, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'04:44:07', 39.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3232983, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'05:35:27', 35.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3232974, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'05:48:10', 35.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3232296, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'09:37:57', 31.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3232232, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'09:48:31', 31.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3232211, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'09:51:56', 31.0000, 'A' ), 
( 3232150, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'10:01:22', 31.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3232145, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'10:01:59', 31.0000, 'D' ), 
( 3232138, '111111XXXXXX1111', 'Vendor1', N'2023-08-18T00:00:00', N'10:03:03', 31.0000, 'D' )
```

Comment: In before someone complains about the image. From my POV this is fine as it is supplementary to the same data provided in text form

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: In truth, the image can probably go, it doesn't *add* anything to the question, and *could* just attract downvotes.

Comment: If you look at a window of the 5 previous rows  + current row and validate that (a) the `MIN(TxnDate)` in that window is within 5 days of current `TxnDate` (b) The Window contains 6 rows and all of them have `Status = 'D'` does this meet the requirement?

Comment: Version is SQL 2017.

Comment: Or do you need that at least one decline happens per day of the six days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the logic you need then you should be able to do everything with a window of `ORDER BY  [TxnDate], [TxnTime] ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, 
        TxnDateTime5RowsPrev = MIN(TxnDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY [Card], [Merchant], [Amount] ORDER BY  [TxnDate], [TxnTime] ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
        NumberOfDeclinesInWindow = sum(IIF([Status] = 'D', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY [Card], [Merchant], [Amount] ORDER BY  [TxnDate], [TxnTime] ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM #temptable
cross apply (values(DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',TxnDate), CAST(TxnTime AS DATETIME2(7))))) ca(TxnDateTime)
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE TxnDateTime5RowsPrev >= DATEADD(DAY, -5, TxnDateTime)  
   AND NumberOfDeclinesInWindow = 6
```

The `NumberOfDeclinesInWindow`  will be `6` if they have 5 consecutive declines plus the current one.

The `MIN(TxnDateTime)` in that window lets you know if all of those were in the  rolling 5-day timeframe

Comment: Not guaranteed to have at least one per day on those 5 days though

Comment: I don't see that specified that there has to be one on each day. Just 5 previous consecutive declines  within 5 days

Comment: True, depends how you read it